# Acer Travelmate P253-M Freezes on BIOS

Tags: bios, laptop

I was trying to create a dual boot of Windows 8 and Ubuntu. I successfully installed Ubuntu on the hard disk but it wasn't able to boot so I went through boot-repair which said that I should put a certain file as EFI. I did that, restarted and only Acer logo appeared with nothing else. F2 didn't work, I couldn't get to BIOS any other way.

What I have tried:

- Reseat the RAM
- Plug-in, plug-out hard drive
- Trying to plug only a bootable flash drive
- Trying to boot from CD
- Downloaded BIOS update from the acer website, but it only has a version from within Windows (which I can't access).
- Shorted JCMOS1 jumper for 20 seconds after which the ACER logo dissapeared and insted:

  - A black screen appears after I press the power key for about 5 seconds and then only a message "Press  to enter Setup." appears
  - If I hold Fn+Esc and then power up, system info appears (Insyde H2O EFI 3.7, Copyright... System BIOS version: v2.13, Processor type etc) and the "Press  to enter Setup." on the bottom
  - On pressing F2 the message "Press  to enter Setup." dissapears but nothing happens

Any other ideas are very welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Updating the [BIOS image](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/GB/content/support-product/4518;-;TravelMate%20P253-M) solved the problem by following the instructions in the README.

Comment: It's best to download directly [from the manufacturer](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/GB/content/professional-drivers/4518;-;TravelMate%20P253-M).  Public upload sites often contain fakes or worse.

Comment: I know this is not content for comment. But still. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! This solution worked like a charm! :) (dance)